# Efficient way to transfer files between hdfs and S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hadoop, hdfs

I'm looking for efficient way to transfer files between S3 and hdfs. In my project a ozzie job is kickedoff it processes files create tmp files and enter into critical section where the job has to obtain zookeeper lock and then perform some operation. One of the operation that it performs after acquiring the lock is moving files from hdfs to S3. Due to the zookeeper lock in place we have few jobs that fail to obtain zookeeper lock due to timeout. In order make sure there are no jobs that fail due to timeout issue, I’m trying improve the efficiency of the file transfer. I can’t eliminate the zookeeper lock either. I’m using InterProcessMutex lock.

I’ve couple of approaches that I tried.

**Approach 1:** I tried to use apache DistCp api using below changes, the project does not build with maven error.

```
final String[] args = new String[4];
          args[0] = "-overwrite";
           args[1] = "-pb";
            args[2] = source.toString();
            args[3] = destination.toString();
            LOGGER.info("Copying contents");
            DistCp distCp = null;
            try {
                DistCpOptions distCpOptions = new DistCpOptions.Builder(source, destination)
                       .withSyncFolder(true)
                        .withCRC(true)
                        .withOverwrite(true)
                       .build();
                distCp = new DistCp(configuration, distCpOptions);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                throw new IOException("An Exception occured while creating a distCp object", e);
            }
           LOGGER.info("Copying contents of source path {} to destination path {} ", source, destination);
           final int distCopyExitCode = distCp.run(args);
```

**Error:**  To rectify this error I saw a suggestion to added  guava-11.0.2 maven dependency, which didn’t fix the issue. Any idea on how to fix this issue?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/thirdparty/com/google/common/base/Preconditions
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCpOptions$Builder.<init>(DistCpOptions.java:530)
```

**Approach 2:**  
I came across aws S3Distcp tool which transfers files between hdfs and S3, however I didn’t find S3Distcp java api. The one way to use S3Distcp is from EMR by creating a step in EMR cluster. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/java-emr-emr-add-steps.java.html)  .

In my scenario,I have a EMR step which actually kickoffs off the jobs, a job will process input files, then moves files from hdfs  to S3 and then terminates.

If I use the solution provided in the above link, below steps will be the sequence of actions.

1. Ozzie Job kicks-off
2. Job process input files and creates tmp file in hdfs
3. Obtain zookeeper lock
4. Create EMR step to trigger file transfer using S3Distcp
5. Transfer files from hdfs to S3
6. EMR Step complete
7. Job Complete

If I use this approach- there are multiple parallel jobs that are kicked offs, for each job there will be a new EMR step that will be created. Correct me if I got it wrong. Can anyone provide suggestion on how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/thirdparty/com/google/common/base/Preconditions
```

This is showing missing hadoop-thirdparty dependency. Adding this should solve this error

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-shaded-guava</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-thirdparty-guava.version}</version>
     </dependency>
```

You can choose the corresponding version as per the hadoop version for this dependency, the latest being 1.1.1 for hadoop version 3.3.3